# Matlab: Is there a way to use something like Macros?

Tags: matlab, macros

I have a function with a Matrix A as input. The functions should perform a blocked algorithm. So, I have want to act on subarrays of A, let's call them A00, A01, A10, etc. For example,

```
A00 = A(1:i*b,1:i*b);
```

To simplify the algorithm I want to use the names A00, A01, A10, etc. inside the algorithm. But I want to write into A.

Here a small example:

```
n = 4; A = zeros(n,n); for i = [1:n*n] A(i) = i; end;

i=1;b=2;

A00 = A(1:i*b,1:i*b);       % here I want to define something like a macro

A00 = eye(b,b);             % here I want to write into A

display(A);
```

The output should be

```
A =

 1     0     9    13
 0     1    10    14
 3     7    11    15
 4     8    12    16
```

Is there something like macros or pointers, or something else in Matlab, that allows me to do exactly that?

My goal is to write the Matlab code more readable, because I act on A00 multiple times and I don't want to write `A(1:i*b,1:i*b)` every time.

Comment: You *could* use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) but personally I think this makes it less readable than using explicit subscripts.

Comment: Why not just `A00 = A(1:i*b,1:i*b);` do your processing on `A00` and then when you're done, `A(1:i*b,1:i*b) = A00`? Also have you looked at the [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) function. Also this way you can stick to `A00` and not have to have `A01` etc as that will certainly make your code unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: Another option would be to just define your indices as variables then use that, i.e. `x=1:i*b; y=1:i*b;` then you can do all your processing on `A(x,y)` which is certainly more readable than `A(1:i*b,1:i*b)`. Granted not as nice as `A00`, but probably more flexible (you can change the values of `x` and `y` in a loop for example).

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
IX       = {1:i*b,1:i*b};
A(IX{:}) = eye(b,b);
B(IX{:}) = rand(b,b);
```

The nearest notion to pointer (in terms of pointer arithmetic) is the index in MATLAB. One may use the same index on several arrays (as long as the indexing is valid). But you still need to "defer" your index to the correct array variable/evaluation result.

Your index may take *any* of the accepted forms: linear, subscript or logical.

I should warn you also that using `i` as name of variable is asking for trouble. `i` and `j` are reserved for defining numeric literals (i.e. "constants") that have imaginary part.